# Swift Hangman Program - Guessing Letters Not Updating/Working Correctly

Tags: swift

I'm creating a hangman game in swift currently, but I'm having some issues with updating the word when you guess a letter.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var Submit: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var secretWord: UILabel!

var wordlist = [String]();
var wordA = [Character]();
var randomIndex: Int = 0;
var word: String = "";



var test: String = "";

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    wordlist = ["orange juice", "waffles", "pancakes", "toast", "poptarts", "bagels", "bacon", "eggs"]

    randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(wordlist.count)))
    //var word = wordlist[randomIndex]
    word = wordlist[1];

    DisplayWord()
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
var letter: String = "";

@IBAction func Submit(sender: AnyObject) {
    var letter = textField.text;
    for(var i = 0; i < wordA.count; i++){
        if(letter == String(wordA[i])){
            wordA[i] = "*";
        }
    }
    DisplayWord();
}
func DisplayWord(){
    test = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < NSString(string: word).length; i++){
        for index in indices(word){
            wordA.append(word[index]);
        }

        if(wordA[i] == " "){
            test += "       ";
        }else if(String(wordA[i]) == "*"){
            test += letter;
        }else{
            test += "_ ";
        }
    }
    secretWord.text = test;
}

}
```

I know I do not have a randomizer to select a random word, I will be adding that later. Same with adding all correct guesses to an array to fix if they guess have guessed that letter already.

When the app opens up it sets the variable/String word = "waffles" for now. then it runs the DisplayWord function to display all the underscores corresponding to the length of the word.

Then next time when you click the Submit button, it scans the word to see if it has the word you guessed. If it does, it sets that letter to an *. Then re-runs the DisplayWord function. It checks if any of the letters are an *, and if it is, instead of adding an "_" to the string, it adds the letter last typed it.

For some reason, it just about doubles the string, and still has all underscores in the label.

**UPDATE: Phoen1xUK has fixed the error about the string doubling, but it replaces the letter you guessed with a space.**

Comment: Well firstly, the reason its doubling the string is because `test` is being appended to each time `DisplayWord()` is called. You should either create `test` inside of that function, or set it to an empty string each time the function is called.

Comment: Print `wordA` at the end of `DisplayWord`. I guess it looks different than you think. Btw, methods should not start with a capital letter.

Comment: Also take the for in loop where you are appending to `wordA` out of `DisplayWord()` because its being called every time and continuously appending to it. I'd suggest you put it where the word is chosen inside of `viewDidLoad()`

Comment: As an aside, you can use `wordA = Array(word)` to make an array of characters from a string. Or if you are using Swift 2 `Array(word.characters)`

Comment: You're getting spaces because you're creating a local letter variable inside of `Submit()` . Change the first line of `Submit()` to `letter = textField.text` . It's not actually spaces you're getting, but instead removing the underscore each time you guessed a letter correctly.

Comment: This however is still incomplete as each time a correct guess is made, all the places that are marked as * will be replaced by that letter. You should instead get the letter that is needed to replace the underscore from the original word rather than the letter that is guessed each time. Then change the if statement to something along the lines of `test += String(originalWord[i]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well firstly, the reason its doubling the string is because `test` is being appended to each time `DisplayWord()` is called. You should either create `test` inside of that function, or set it to an empty string each time the function is called.

You're getting spaces because you're creating a local letter variable inside of `Submit()` and not changing the letter which will be used in `DisplayWord()` - so you could remove the `var` from the first line in `Submit()`.

This however is still incomplete as each time a correct guess is made, all the places that are marked as * will be replaced by that letter. You should instead get the letter that is needed to replace the underscore from the original word rather than the letter that is guessed each time. Then change the if statement to something along the lines of `test += String(originalWord[i]);`

Also take the for in loop where you are appending to `wordA` out of `DisplayWord()` because its being called every time and continuously appending to it. I'd suggest you put it where the word is chosen inside of `viewDidLoad()`. As an aside, you can use `wordA = Array(word)` to make an array of characters from a string. Or if you are using Swift 2: `Array(word.characters)`.

To summarise:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var Submit: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var secretWord: UILabel!

    var wordlist = [String]();
    var wordA = [Character]();
    var randomIndex: Int = 0;
    var word: String = "";
    var test: String = "";

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        wordlist = ["orange juice", "waffles", "pancakes", "toast", "poptarts", "bagels", "bacon", "eggs"]

        randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(wordlist.count)))
        word = wordlist[randomIndex]

        wordA = Array(word)

        DisplayWord()
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func Submit(sender: AnyObject) {
        let letter = textField.text;
        for(var i = 0; i < wordA.count; i++){
            if(letter == String(wordA[i])){
                wordA[i] = "*";
            }
        }
        DisplayWord();
    }

    func DisplayWord(){
        test = "";
        for(var i = 0; i < NSString(string: word).length; i++){
            if(wordA[i] == " "){
                test += "       ";
            }else if(String(wordA[i]) == "*") {
                test += String(Array(word)[i]);
            }else{
                test += "_ ";
            }
        }
        secretWord.text = test;
    }
}
```

And as [mentioned by dasdom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31678764/swift-hangman-program-guessing-letters-not-updating-working-correctly#comment51300410_31678764), it's common practice to start methods with a lower case letter.